# Keyboard doesn't work correctly and Power button is off

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, bios

I don't why suddenly my keyboard's lights turned off and and when I turn on system it went to initramfs prompt and it reported:

> /dev/sda5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

I used that and I could come back to desktop, but I don't know why my keyboard has been messed up.

For example when I press 'i' it opens the search bar and when I use L it shows l with the \ character.In addition when I turn on my lap top bios doesn't check  the DVD Drive
I wrote this question with a lot of effort.
I hope you would answer .

Comment: Is it possible that some liquid was accidentally spilled onto the laptop? In any case, the problems with the DVD drive in BIOS suggest physical damage of some sort.

Comment: if keyboard does not work in BIOS setup, then your question is not about Ubuntu

Comment: @telcoM yes I think that would be , because I was cleaning my lap top before the Issue appeared .by the way , my lap top is Lenovo Ideapad 320 and Its latest version of Bios   is  for Ubuntu  16.04 . Is it possible that would be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard malfunction seems typical for water (or other liquid) damage: the liquid has entered the keyboard wiring matrix and is causing short circuits in it.

If the DVD drive has also started to fail at the same time, it's possible that both faults have the same root cause. Water intrusion is unfortunately a rather common reason for laptop failures.

[The "Safety and General Information Guide" for Lenovo laptops](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/safety_and_general_information_guide_english.pdf) has instructions for cleaning the computer in Chapter 2:

> **Cleaning the cover of your computer**
>
> Occasionally clean your computer as follows:
>
> 1 Prepare a mixture of a gentle kitchen-use detergent (one that does not
> contain abrasive powder or strong chemicals such as acid or alkaline).
> Use 5 parts water to 1 part detergent.
>
> 2 Absorb the diluted detergent into a sponge.
>
> 3 Squeeze excess liquid from the sponge.
>
> 4 Wipe the cover with the sponge, using a circular motion and taking care not to let any excess liquid drip.
>
> 5 Wipe the surface to remove the detergent.
>
> 6 Rinse the sponge with clean running water.
>
> 7 Wipe the cover with the clean sponge.
>
> 8 Wipe the surface again with a dry, soft lint-free cloth.
>
> 9 Wait for the surface to dry completely and remove any cloth fibers from the computer surface.
>
> Note: Shut down the computer and then disconnect the power cord before
> cleaning the computer.
>
> **Cleaning your computer keyboard**
>
> 1 Absorb some isopropyl rubbing alcohol on a soft, dust-free cloth.
>
> 2 Wipe each keytop surface with the cloth. Wipe the keys one by one; if you wipe several keys at a time, the cloth may hook onto an adjacent key and possibly damage it. Make sure that no liquid drips onto or between the
> keys.
>
> 3 Allow to dry.
>
> 4 To remove any crumbs and dust from beneath the keys, you can use a
> camera blower with a brush or cool air from a hair drier.
>
> Note: Avoid spraying cleaner directly on the display or the keyboard.

Comment: I brought my lap top to repair shop and they changed my keyboard ,keyboard works well now ,but my lap top get off when I seprate the charger , may It's related to long time being off ?

Comment: If the laptop’s battery has been unused for a long time, it may have self-discharged and eventually become damaged because of deep discharge. You might want to post a separate question on battery care; each StackExchange question is supposed to be about one topic only.